# Curious about what would happen or curious what would happen?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, ellipsis

I know that

> I am curious what would happen

is a perfectly valid usage. What I don't understand is why there is no preposition to connect "curious" and "what would happen", which is acting like a noun clause. It seems to me that the sentence is not grammatical and needs "about" between curious and what would happen. Why is it an acceptable usage? Is there a grammar rule behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are idiomatic.  With the version without the preposition, **curious** is treated as if it means "desiring to know".

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/prepositions/

There's no preposition, because you don't need it.  When you take a technical writing course, there's a lot of focus on removing unnecessary prepositions, and that was the first thing I thought of when I read your question.

I don't think "I'm curious about what would happen" is wrong, it's just superfluous.

Try extending the thought of the original sentence: I am curious about what would happen if I open that door.

vs

I am curious what would happen if I open that door.